# On proving $\partial_\theta^n\int_0^1t^{\theta-1}\,\mathrm dt=\int_0^1\partial_\theta^nt^{\theta-1}\,\mathrm dt$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $n=1,2\dots$ and $\theta\in(0,\infty)$. I want to prove
$$
\partial_\theta^n\int_0^1t^{\theta-1}\,\mathrm dt=\int_0^1\partial_x^nt^{\theta-1}\,\mathrm dt.
$$
I was using [this](http://www.math.caltech.edu/%7E2016-17/2term/ma003/Notes/DifferentiatingAnIntegral.pdf) document as a reference for understanding the conditions under which integration and differentiation can be interchanged. Using the notation in the linked paper: $\Theta=(0,\infty)$, $X=[0,1]$, and $g:\Theta\times X\to \Bbb R$ with $g(\theta,x)=x^{\theta-1}$.

Clearly,
$$
\int_0^1|g(\theta,x)|\,\mathrm dx<\infty,\quad\forall\theta\in\Theta.
$$
Furthermore, its easy to show that $|\partial_\theta^ng(\theta,x)|=(-\log x)^{n}x^{a-1}$ and
$$
\int_0^1|\partial_\theta^ng(\theta,x)|\,\mathrm dx<\infty,\quad\forall\theta\in\Theta.
$$
If I am understanding correctly, all that is left to show is uniform local integrability. If so, I have to show for all $\theta_0\in\Theta$ that there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that
$$
\sup_{\theta\in(\theta_0-\epsilon,\theta_0+\epsilon)}|\partial_\theta^ng(\theta,x)|\leq h(x),
$$
where $\int_0^1h(x)\,\mathrm dx<\infty$. But how do I find the dominating function $h$? It is true that
$$
\sup_{\theta\in(\theta_0-\epsilon,\theta_0+\epsilon)}|\partial_\theta^ng(\theta,x)|\leq (-\log x)^n x^{\theta_0-\epsilon-1},
$$
which is integrable if $\theta_0>\epsilon$. Since I could choose $\epsilon=\theta_0/2$ it would seem I can always find a dominating function that is integrbale, however, this dominating function is not independent of $\theta$.

> How to I prove the uniform local uniform integrability condition here to finish the proof?

Comment: You are actually done! Since differentiation is a local property, you just need that your integrand is dominated by an integrable function, _locally uniformly_ in $\theta.$

Comment: @Ignatius Would you be willing to spell this out in an answer for me? I'm not understanding your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that
$$\partial^k_{\theta} (x^{\theta-1}) = x^{\theta-1} \log^k x.$$

Let $\theta_0 > 0.$
Then, for $\theta \in [\theta_{0},\infty)$ we have
$$|x^{\theta-1}\log^k x| \leq x^{\theta_0-1} |\log^k x|$$
for all $x \in (0,1),$
and the right hand side is integrable, independent of $\theta$.

By the criterion above, the function $\theta \mapsto \int_0^1 x^{\theta-1} d x$ is $k$ times differentiable in $(\theta_0, \infty)$ with $k$-th derivative $\int_0^1 x^{\theta-1} \log^k x \,d x.$
Since $\theta_0 > 0$ was arbitrary, it follows that the function is $k$ times differentiable in $(0,\infty).$